# Inkscape: Smooth blur effect

Tags: inkscape, blur

I am following a tutorial which is far too quick for me to see what is being done, I am trying to smooth a kind of blur effect, it looks like it's blur being used, but when I try something similar it doesn't seem to achieve the same effect, infact it looks pretty bad.

This is the tutorial:
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YR1UNz3jKGo)

Here are images of the desired effect (on the right)and my before and after attempt:

[image]

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

After watching the tutorial you linked to I agree that the steps are too fast, and hard to follow. Nevertheless my avatar was created using similar effects so I am going to post the steps I took:

1. Create a radial fill gradient in a slightly blurred circle

   [image]
2. Add white circle to create highlight

   [image]
3. Blur the white circle

   [image]

Comment: That looks great! Thanks, I'll give that a try instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you can't see in that almost useless tutorial is that the blurred shapes are contained inside a clipping mask.

Create all the shapes, group the internal shapes that are to be blurred, then select the outer most shape, and Copy and Paste in Place. Select both outer shape and inner group, then click Object > Clip > Set.

Then using the Edit Paths by Nodes Tool, select each shape and apply the blur you need.

[image]

Comment: I'm still getting fuzzy white edges to my object being blurred, (in your object it would be the places where they light pink meets the darker pink and the darker pink meets the red) how did you avoid this? Thanks again.

Comment: - * Nevermind, I sorted it, thanks for your help, things look much better!